# .net 4.5.2 reference not recognized

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have inherited a MVC 3 project where the previous developer developed using VS2010. I am using VS2015 Enterprise. I am in the process of upgrading the application to .net framework 4.5.2.

I have updated references but am still running into the following error:

The type or namespace 'RoleProvider' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference". I have the current System.Web.ApplicationServices reference.

Any ideas of a step I may be missing? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Nuget to uninstall the old Membership providers and add in the new one.

Comment: Looks like it may be an issue with the System.Web.ApplicationServices reference. I updated the reference for .net 4.5.2 but still getting error that 'RoleProvider, MembershipProvider, Membershup User, and MembershipUsercollection' could not be found.